# SDL unicode keyboard input: filter none character inputs

Tags: c++, sdl, emscripten

I'm using this code to to determine keyboard inputs as unicode character:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    switch (event.type)
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        {
            SDL_KeyboardEvent* keyboard = (reinterpret_cast<SDL_KeyboardEvent*> (&event));

            //unicode input
            std::cout << (int)keyboard->keysym.unicode << std::endl;

            //conversion
            ...

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that `keysym.unicode` has also a value if I would only press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-key (printed value is 1249).

But I only need valid unicode-charactars (e.g.: pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Any hints?

Comment: State whether you're using SDL1 or SDL2. I suspect 1, since you're using the unicode field.

Comment: I'm using this code inside emscripten compiled code. I do not know which version they have implemented

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to find out then. Unicode is [handled differently](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#Input) in SDL2. If what you have right now does compile though then it's likely SDL1.

Comment: looks like if they are using 1.3. But `SDL_TEXTINPUT` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using: `SDL_StartTextInput();` to enable textinput-events with:

`SDL_TEXTINPUT`-event instead of `SDL_KEYDOWN` is working fine.